# recover last state of full lvm snapshot

Tags: lvm, device-mapper

I recently ran into the case that an LVM snapshot overflowed. The reasons are unclear:
* there was probably no write access to the origin at all
* both snapshot and origin have same size (100g, 25600 extends)
* according to the documentation this should never happen in this case

Now I would like to attempt to recover (part) the disk from the last state.
I would assume that most of the disk should be still in a reasonable state and somewhere in my volume group.
However I could not find a way to do this, a simple dd fails with read errors.

In case it matters, the volume contains a virtual machine.